# Linux named sockets howto

Tags: linux, sockets

I know that there are named sockets & named pipes (fifo) in Linux.

In `ls -l`, they would look as below: (I have changed the filenames, for demonstration.)

```
prw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  8 16:31 /tmp/fifo
srwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  8 15:54 /tmp/socket
```

Now, a named pipe can be created using `mkfifo`. Is there a command for creating a named socket?

Last option would be to write a C program, which would call mknod function, but wanted to know, if there is already a command for that.

What I have tried:
I tried to search for any options to mknod & mkfifo, but could not find one.

NOTE: I am not discussing about server-client model over Ethernet/network. The named socket file will be used by 2 processes on the same system.

Comment: Just a note: I have 2 processes - qemu & virsh, which can talk to each other using named socket (as per my understanding based on the documentation) But I don't know how to create a named socket. While there ARE other options to use virsh with qemu, I was looking for an option, wherein I can attach virsh to an existing qemu process & it needs a named *socket*, while starting the qemu process. Named fifo don't work. Plus, I think, it will be an interesting to know how to create named socket, in case it is required later.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A Unix/Linux socket file is basically a two-way FIFO. 
Since sockets were originally created
as a way to manage network communications,
it is possible to manipulate them
using the `send()` and `recv()` system calls. 
However, in the Unix spirit of “everything is a file”,
you can also use `write()` and `read()`. 
You need to use `socketpair()` or `socket()` to create named sockets. 
A tutorial for using sockets in C can be found here:
[Beej's Guide to Unix IPC: Unix Sockets](https://beej.us/guide/bgipc/html/multi/unixsock.html).

The `socat` command line utility is useful when you want to play around with sockets without writing a "real" program.  It is similar to `netcat` and acts as an adapter between different networking and file interfaces.

**Links:**

- [`socat` project home](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/)
- [An introduction to `socat`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-tcp-port-forwarding/)
- [Interesting article about Unix sockets and `socat`](http://matt.scharley.me/2012/03/debugging-application-interactions-with-socat.html)

Comment: socketpair() or socket() creates an un-named socket, which will be useful only from within the C program.

Comment: It would be interesting to check, if it is possible to create a named socket using `socat`. Probably, create an un-named socket, bind it to localhost:some_port & then use socat with that port?

Comment: It is possible to create named sockets using `socat` with the UNIX-LISTEN command, see `man socat` or [this HTML manual](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html)

Comment: I tried this quick & dirty command and it created a socket file `f1`: `socat UNIX-LISTEN:f1 LISTEN:f2`.

Comment: It's buried in the details of the socat website, but in case it's helpful, there's a syntax for treating two unidirectional named pipes (fifo's) as a single bidirectional unit that can be bridged to other bidirectional entities like Unix or TCP sockets. You join the named pipes with `!!` (socat 1.x) or `%` (socat 2.x), with the writing named pipe on the left and the reading named pipe on the right. e.g. `socat 'PIPE:/tmp/outstream!!PIPE:/tmp/instream' UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/mysocket`

Comment: Can you please quote the relevant parts of the linked document? It's hard to find how can I create a named socket.

Answer (score 19):

Create a socket quickly in python:

```
~]# python -c "import socket as s; sock = s.socket(s.AF_UNIX); sock.bind('/tmp/somesocket')"
~]# ll /tmp/somesocket 
srwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 0 Mar  3 19:30 /tmp/somesocket
```

Or [with a tiny C program](https://gist.github.com/ryran/170009f84c11bf3243b1), e.g., save the following to `create-a-socket.c`:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // The following line expects the socket path to be first argument
    char * mysocketpath = argv[1];
    // Alternatively, you could comment that and set it statically:
    //char * mysocketpath = "/tmp/mysock";
    struct sockaddr_un namesock;
    int fd;
    namesock.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(namesock.sun_path, (char *)mysocketpath, sizeof(namesock.sun_path));
    fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &namesock, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Then install gcc, compile it, and ta-da:

```
~]# gcc -o create-a-socket create-a-socket.c
~]# ./create-a-socket mysock
~]# ll mysock
srwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 0 Mar  3 17:45 mysock
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no commmand line tool to create sockets since a socket is always connect to a server which handles the requests sent to that socket.

So you will have to write a server and let that create the socket. [Here is a tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20121124063435/http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html).

Comment: That would still be an un-named socket. I want to create a socket, which would be used by 2 other processes, as bidirectional fifo.

Comment: Check the link in my answer. It shows how to configure `bind()` to connect to `"/home/beej/mysocket"`